# C UNIX - How to use multiple sockets server-side to receive UDP messages in order to filter them?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, udp, filtering

I am writing UDP server and client in C on UNIX. I need to handle each client in its own thread on server. In each thread, I want to receive only messages from corresponding client. Right now I am peeking messages using recvfrom and checking message whether it is "mine".

I heard that it is possible to have multiple sockets listening on the same host:port and connect each of them to corresponding client so it will receive messages only from the said client. Here is the code I run when I run into new client. However, after first client connects messages are in fact filtered, but not only on new socket, but also on main socket listening for new clients, so I cant connect new clients.

```
void fun(int* sockfd, struct sockaddr_in* my_addr, struct sockaddr_in* cli_addr)){
if ((*sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    ERR("socket");
}

int optval = 1;
bzero(my_addr, sizeof (*my_addr));
my_addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr->sin_port = htons(PORT);
my_addr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof (optval)) < 0) {
    ERR("setsockopt");
}
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) my_addr, sizeof (*my_addr)) == -1) {
    ERR("bind");
}

if (connect(*socket, (struct sockaddr*) cli_addr, sizeof (*cli_addr)) < 0)
    ERR("connect");
}
}
```

Is there a better (and working) way to filter UDP messages?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use one thread for receiving and sending data and then dispatch to the other threads.

There is no need for more than one socket server side. One socket receive all datagrams, you process them by extracting the source, and then dispatch it.

You could do something like this:

Datagram is read:

- source is known, call the backback you have for it
- source is not known, create a new thread, and register a callback for this source.
- Whenever you want to "disconnect" a client, unregister the callback and remove the thread.

Note that by "disconnect" I mean in a logical way for your application, since UDP socket are not connected.